# How can we encourage people to use all their votes on an election?

Tags: discussion, voting, election

I'm seeing people who's votes are up+down less than 60, and others who have up+down votes closer to 320, and we're only an hour or so in to the election process.

Doing some back of the napkin math I come up with 260 people so far only voting for one person, or a handful, and leaving.

Can we encourage people to (maybe only giving the badge today-forward on elections for voting if they) use all (*or more than one of*) their votes?

Is there merit in that proposal? Or am I just messing with a working system?

#### EDIT:

I think what I'm really getting at, with some help from friends in refinement, is: **If you only cast one vote in the election, are you really helping to determine new mods, or are your votes just chaff that should be discarded or somehow counted for less?**

Comment: I WAS WONDERING THE SAME THING

Comment: What about my "Meh" votes? (+0)

Comment: Limit the field to users they all know and they'll vote. Otherwise, abstained.

Comment: There are some candidates I really want to make it to the election phase. I upvote them. Downvotes are reserved for people I really would rather not see in the final stage. Those who I neither favour nor object to, stay unvoted (by me).

Comment: That's a good policy Daniel, and what I think Robert was getting at. However, I have some interaction with almost everyone on that list, and have looked into all of them enough to have a decision if not previously interacted with. So I'm all for casting all my votes, because I've put that effort into it. I also have a policy of "upvote anything that's not crap, downvote the crap"

Comment: [All 72 of them?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135557/whats-with-all-these-election-notifications)

Comment: @jcolebrand But if I upvote all, or all but one or two, my votes have less influence than when I vote only for or against those I have a decided opinion on. That would level the ones I like and the ones I don't dislike.

Comment: Wait, did I say to only upvote people? I upvoted the ones I wanted to see make it to the final election (more than 10) and downvoted the rest. The policy of upvoting anything that's not crap generally tends to apply to my SE question wanderings, as often as I come across SE posts, I'll vote for everything on the page (not all the comments, just the posts) up to my daily limit. Some days I don't make it on the network. Same goes for reddit.  ~~ Maybe my point is, surely you want to see more than one person make it to the final round?

Comment: @jcolebrand: That's mighty black and white of you.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Maybe so, but these are moderators involved, I think that we should make a firm decision on who we want to be moderators. I never said I was right, I actually was asking for community input and feedback.

Comment: @jcolebrand Sure I want to see more than one in the finals. And I have cast more than one vote. But I haven't voted on all candidates, and won't. Among those I don't favour, there are enough who are definitely not worth a downvote.

Comment: Thanks everybody, and keep the feedback coming. I didn't figure this carried merit, but I was curious what the community thought.

Comment: I think the current echo chamber is working "as designed."

Comment: @CodeGnome it is, and it is working great, isn't it?

Comment: Hey everybody who commented so far, consider this alternate to the question: If you only cast one vote in the election, are you truly participating? (editing to add this in)

Comment: @jcolebrand - if you honestly only wanted one person to win and felt so strongly about that one person that you didn't care out of the others I'd say yes. It'd be dishonest to vote for more just because you can.

Comment: The great thing about voting systems which are more than single vote, first past the post voting is that you can be flexible in the way you use them to more accurately express your views. That they can degrade to simple FPTP voting if people desire is a testament to their expressiveness.

Comment: With all due respect sir, my initial reaction is "If this is what you have time to talk about, I'm not sure I can vote for you."

Comment: @jcolebrand: "If you only cast one vote in the election, are you truly participating?" I'm with JP here: the very fact that you asked this question made me vote against you. And since I already upvoted someone else, I guess that means I "truly participated." Thanks!

Comment: @JP. that's cool, and I don't have an issue with that. This is really the only time we can see _massive participation_ and so the only time that this can be fishbowled. Any other election just pales in comparison, especially with the new badge notifications etc. If this makes you not want to vote for me, so be it.

Comment: @NicolBolas lol, thanks for your honesty. I don't mind the downvotes, and like I mentioned to him, this is the only time we can even examine the options.

Comment: @awoodland I agree with you on this, I can only ask, as I mentioned just moments ago, when we actually have a fishbowl environment to compare against.

Comment: Again I want to thank everyone for their comments, you're absolutely helping me with this. I just figured this was the opportune time (in this particular election) to observe the mechanics of voting because we're not always gauranteed to get any sort of turnout resembling this at any other time. You can castrate me all you want, and I don't have a problem with that, never have. I don't understand why people make the choices they make, and meta helps me have clarity. Thanks again for your input, regardless what you think about me.

Comment: viva la Stack Exchange

Comment: @jcolebrand I respectfully disagree. An election, which is still ongoing _and of which you are a candidate_, is exactly the wrong time to start suggesting that some votes not be counted. No doubt if the people who vote for only one candidate had their votes discounted, some of the votes for candidates other than yourself wouldn't be counted.

Comment: @JP. do you really think I stand to be elected? I'm in the lower half, and when I posted the question I was already trailing the rear. Do you not think the needs of the site should always be considered? Also, remind me what your experience with the site is? A 2 year old account and you're not even able to close yet? And yet you want to tell me that I'm in the wrong for asking if we need to consider new network policies while running in the same election I'm asking about?

Answer (score 9):

I personally wouldn't use just one vote - but hey, it's a free election, and everyone can do as they please. I don't think the system should mess with people's voting in any way.

> If you only cast one vote in the election, are you really helping to determine new mods, or are your votes just chaff that should be discarded or somehow counted for less?

A vote is a vote. Many people will rationally abstain from voting if they don't know the candidate*, and I don't think that reduces the value of those votes they cast. Quite the contrary actually.

Comment: * at least in US House elections. I happen to have finished a political sciences paper yesterday that deals with this exact issue :)

Comment: really? the `*` in the comments? that _almost_ prevented me to +1 this...

Comment: As always, Pekka shows great insight into the system, and I still wonder why he isn't throwing his hat into the ring (I know why)